# WPF It is possible to embed xbap in Wpf desktop application

Tags: wpf-4.0

Hi i need to create desktop application instead xbap application with the same functionality as it was in xbap application. I am wondering it is possible to embed it in wpf application and how it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do it. And it is quite easy but it can be done in many ways. You can create a dll from you current xbap application but just take the necessary. And create a new WPF application project then just add the reference to the xbap dll that you just made. And then you can use the controls/pages you made in the wpf application

Or you can look at this : 
http://zainco.blogspot.ca/2009/01/converting-xbap-to-wpf-application.html
 or
http://davidsandor.com/post/2009/07/17/Convert-a-WPF-Browser-Application-project-to-a-WPF-Application.aspx

EDIT 1:

In the code behind of the MainWindow you can do something like this.

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.Content = new Page1(); <--- The start page of you xamp application in the dll file.
    }
}
```

Or you can use a NavigationWindow
look at this : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0f100d/navigation-window-based-application-in-wpf/

Comment: how to use then with wfp desktop app i created from xbap dll and how it works ?

Comment: @Goncarz Its kinda hard for me to tell you what to do without seeing your applicaiton. But i guess its build with pages right ?

Comment: right i can show You code but i think it will be too much complicated to explain me. I create simple wpf browser application on the page i add some buttons i changed to be a class library and then compile. Then i create wpf desktop application and add reference to the prevously created browser application this is my code :  `code`public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
           // WpfBrowserApplication1.App app = new WpfBrowserApplication1.App();
            WpfBrowserApplication1.App app1 = new    WpfBrowserApplication1.App();
            app1.Run();
        }`code`

Comment: @Goncarz what you do is in the MainWindow of your wpf app. You use the pages as content from the xbap dll, like you use usercontrols in wpf application.

Comment: Ok if i understand i need create all pages that i have in my xbap application and then i append for example to stackpanel ?

Comment: Can you give me some example how to do it ?

Comment: @Goncarz You dont have to recreate all pages because they already exixts in your dll. But wait i will update my answer with examples.